# Change overlay content dynamically in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to achieve, that content in the overlay would be changed dynamically from other parts of the code. However, this is not updating the label, and content stays the same - "Overlay Content"
How to update content in overlay after the mainloop method has been called without using the buttons?

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

label = None
def initOverlay():
    overlay = tk.Tk()
    overlay.title("Test overlay")
    overlay.geometry("400x300")
    label = tk.Label(overlay, text="Overlay Content")
    label.pack()
    overlay.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
    overlay.geometry("+100+100")
    overlay.mainloop()
    
def changeContent(text):
    label.config(text=text)
    label.pack()

initOverlay()
changeContent("new_text")
```

Comment: `label` inside `initOverlay()` is local variable, not the global one.

Comment: On line 16, comment `out #label.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter [`mainloop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) blocks any code that comes after it from running until you close the window on which you called the method.

It means that the following:

```
changeContent("new_text")
```

Won't run until you close your main window.

In addition, `label` is defined locally in your `initOverlay` and it doesn't change the global `label` variable (so inside `changeContent`, `label` is `None`).

If you want to update the label after the window was lunched you can use [`after`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) method:

```
import tkinter as tk

label = None
def initOverlay():
    global label # Using global label
    overlay = tk.Tk()
    overlay.title("Test overlay")
    overlay.geometry("400x300")
    label = tk.Label(overlay, text="Overlay Content")
    label.pack()
    overlay.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
    overlay.geometry("+100+100")
    label.after(10 * 1000, changeContent, "new_text") # call 'changeContent' function after 10 seconds
    overlay.mainloop()
    
def changeContent(text):
    label.config(text=text)
    label.pack()

initOverlay()
```

This will change the text in `label` after `10` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the overlay in other process + create Queue where you put data from other parts of the code you want to show in the label.

For example:

```py
import multiprocessing
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep


class CustomOverlayProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        overlay = tk.Tk()

        self.overlay = overlay

        overlay.title("Test overlay")
        overlay.geometry("400x300")
        self.label = tk.Label(overlay, text="Overlay Content")
        self.label.pack()
        overlay.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
        overlay.geometry("+100+100")

        overlay.after(100, self.refresh_data)

        overlay.mainloop()

    def refresh_data(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.label.config(text=text)
            self.label.pack()

        self.overlay.after(100, self.refresh_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # create custom overlay process with a queue
    overlay_process = CustomOverlayProcess(the_queue)
    overlay_process.start()

    # simulate some work:
    for i in range(1, 5):
        the_queue.put(f"Event {i}")  # <-- put the data to the queue
        sleep(1)

    # terminate the overlay process
    overlay_process.terminate()
    overlay_process.join()
```